# postgis declare variable and combine this with select

Tags: postgresql, gis, geospatial, postgis, pgadmin

I like to declare a variable in pgadmin, and use it to make some calculation for creating a view. This is my template, how can i fix this code to get a table in pgadmin

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
 A numeric(11,2) := 1;
 B numeric(11,2) := 14.3;
 C numeric(11,2) := 0.33;
BEGIN  -- maybe the bug
Select 
 tablex.coly,
 sum(tablex.colx * A) as a_colx,
 sum(tablex.colx * B) as b_colx,
 sum(tablex.colx * C) as c_colx
FROM tablex
GROUP BY tablex.coly
END$$;
```